# Hyperledger fabric 2.0: committed with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to experiment  HLF 2.0 chain code lifecycle following the [official doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/deploy_chaincode.html)

The network has 3 ordering nodes with two orgs and one peer each

But on the chain code commit I am getting the error

```
committed with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE) at peer1.base.right:9051
```

**configtx.yml**

```
     Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        Name: LeftOrgMSP
        ID: LeftOrgMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/base.left/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.admin', 'LeftOrgMSP.peer', 'LeftOrgMSP.client','LeftOrgMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.admin', 'LeftOrgMSP.client','LeftOrgMSP.peer','LeftOrgMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.admin','LeftOrgMSP.peer')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('LeftOrgMSP.peer')"    
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.base.left
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        Name: RightOrgMSP
        ID: RightOrgMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/base.right/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.admin', 'RightOrgMSP.peer', 'RightOrgMSP.client','RightOrgMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.admin','RightOrgMSP.peer', 'RightOrgMSP.client','RightOrgMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.admin','RightOrgMSP.peer')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('RightOrgMSP.peer')"     

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.base.right
              Port: 9051            

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
       V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
       V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"   
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"    


    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"


    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    MainChannel:
        Consortium: BaseConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    Raft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                - Host: orderer1.base.order
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer2.base.order
                  Port: 8050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer3.base.order
                  Port: 9050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/tls/server.crt



            Addresses:
                - orderer1.base.order:7050
                - orderer2.base.order:8050
                - orderer3.base.order:9050

            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            BaseConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
```

While checking the read commit ness I am having the desired output

```
{
    "approvals": {
        "LeftOrgMSP": true,
        "RightOrgMSP": true
    }
}
```

**Chaincode approve**

```
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg  --channelID basechannel --name fabcar --version 1.0 --init-required --package-id fabcar_1:206a5ce87aefb8b9780b75451523c2aa3ef718ceebaaeae5082ae88ea259b305 --sequence 1 -o orderer1.base.order:7050  --tls --cafile $CA_PATH
```

**Chaincode commit command**

```
peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer1.base.order:7050 --channelID basechannel --name fabcar --version 1.0 --sequence 1 --init-required --tls true --cafile $ORDER_CA_PATH  --peerAddresses peer1.base.right:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles $PATH_RIGHT --peerAddresses peer1.base.left:7051  --tlsRootCertFiles   $PATH_LEFT
```

Not sure why I m getting that error

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Same thing happening to me.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any solution after all?

Answer (score 0):

I am considering the fact that all the peers containers are up and MSP names are right.

It seems like the block validation policy is missing.

```
 BlockValidation:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
```

Comment: Can you share the chaincode instantiate command and also the full configtx.yaml file.

Comment: I am using HLF 2.0 Updated the question

Comment: okay,can you share the policy command,where you define the policy like AND ('Org1.peer').

Comment: i didn't specify the polices its the default one

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem two days ago and I just solved it. There was nothing wrong with my configuration files and operations before committing the chaincode, but I still got ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE. After checking the debug log ,I found that you are supposed to **commit the chaincode to enough endorsement nodes at the same time to get enough signatures** to make sure that endorsement will be successful, there was more than 30 orgs in my fabric network but in the very beginning I only committed the chaincode to one node, this was no surprise I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. When I was invoking the chaincode I was including as `--peerAddresses` only one of the two peers that I have in my network. And as my policy says, it needs `MAJORITY Endorsement` in Endorsement Policy. So, I had to include 2/2 peers in the invoke command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my blockchain used to be version 1.4 and I created the channel after migrating, it was missing the policy "endorsement" needed for lifecycle endorsement and endorsement, and some capabilities where under 2.0